# How to maximize reuse across many Angular projects?

Tags: angular, angular5

Creating ONE android project is super-easy. Simply install Angular Cli via `npm install -g @angular/cli` and after that create a project via `ng new project_name`.

For ONE and only ONE project everything is super amazing.
Yet when it comes to real-world corporate requirements, it's not that fun anymore.

We're a company with more than 100 web applications (and a vision of more than 500 if we can handle the infrastructure correctly and efficiently). That means that if we want to migrate to Angular, we need to do that `ng new x` 100 times. That's not cool anymore. Because each Angular project is created with almost 30 default files, and some files are highly complicated for managing dependencies.

One very efficient way to create business-value at corporate levels is to have a corporate standard. What if we want all of our projects to use the same version of all tools, so that pair programming would become piece a cake? What if we have decided that we don't want to write tests, and we don't want to have all those testing infra in each and every project? (after all, the cheapest way of maintaining a code, is to not write that code at all).

What if we want to implement the spirit of IoC in the file-system architecture, that is, instead of each developer deciding what he wants, a bigger team of senior developers decide what ALL projects want?

How can we reduce that number of initial files in Angular projects? How can we inherit some of those files? Like for example the `project.json` inheriting from `corporateProject.json` or `tsconfig.json` inheriting from a central corporate-decided TypeScript configuration?

I mean, we can't just have 100 or more completely isolated projects that start to deviate from each other. That's toooooo expensive in the context of real-world business. We need to do some centralization after all to keep costs as low as possible, so that we can deliver products with lower costs to our customers and stay competitive.

For example, we don't want each developer to decide what charting library to use, we want them to already have a charting library being referenced in their projects by a bigger context, so that they will all use that. And please don't tell me that it can be handled by *asking* developers to do so. No that's not the way. It should be automatic and machine-based.

Based on what we wrote in this [GitHub feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21352), we know about [Nx](https://nrwl.io/nx). But it's based on a monorepo, which is somehow not possible in our case, and truly not a beautiful clean scalable solution.

We seem to not be able to find good solutions on the Internet, because most of them are about creating ONE simple dummy project.

How to maximize reuse across many Angular projects, including boilerplate configuration files and the overall file-system architecture?